# Save POST to member profile

Tags: php, mysql, post, joomla

Using Joomla 3.3.3

I have a members only website that requires an invitation code to register.  Once you put in the invitation code, you are brought to the registration form. I need that Invitation Code that the user enters to stay with them throughout the registration process and show on their user profile after registration.

I was able to POST the Invitation Code on the Registration Form, but when you submit the registration, the Code is not saved to the user profile.  So my questions is, how would I save that posted information to the users profile when they submit registration form?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check my previous post that may  help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25658676/3834042

Comment: As this question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be using a User Profile plugin… [the Joomla Doc's site](http://docs.joomla.org/) has a [tutorial on it here](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin).

That allows you to define a new field and store it along with the other user details.